Column value is getting split while exporting from dbeaver to csv
I am trying to export data from Dbeaver to csv . My data looks like this .



group_id
name




103
Pen,Inc.



When I am exporting it in csv  and opening it by double clicking it because of , in between Pen and Inc. it is splitting in multiple column

Details in DBeaver is as follows :

Encoding is UTF-8
Not getting why it is getting split

Instead of double clicking to open the file in Excel, what happens if you right click and open with Notepad?

I think its opening fine in notepad , but I  need to open it in excel and then split on basis of delimiter which is ;

In Excel, go to Data --> From Text/CSV. Then select your file, click Import, and finally, Load.
I replicated your table in DBeaver and this method worked well.

Thank you @FernandoBarbosa option you suggested solved my problem

@pbh With Excel, Importing, using either Get&Transform or the Legacy Import Wizard is a much more robust method and avoids many of the problems that arise when Excel tries to figure out what you have when you double-click or open the file.
